# ReactJs - show another field on selection of specific value in dropdown

Tags: javascript, reactjs

what I am trying is like this:

```
const [selectedCategory, setSelectedCategory] = useState(null);

<div className="col-12 col-lg-12 mb-3">
                    <Select placeholder="Select Category..."
                        id="selectCategory"
                        required
                        defaultValue={selectedCategory}
                        //onKeyUp={setCategory}
                        onChange={setSelectedCategory}                                                
                        options={serviceNames}
                      />
                    </div>
                    <React.Fragment>
                    <div className="col-12 col-lg-12">
                  
                    {selectedCategory.value==="other" && <input 
                        className="form-control mb-3" 
                        id="serviceCategory" 
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Entery Category of your Serivce/business" 
                        name="serviceCategory" 
                        onChange={(e)=>setNewCategory(e.target.value)}
                         />}
                    </div>
                    </React.Fragment>
```

The problem I am having is - I am getting the error like
`selectedCategory.value` is null and page is not rendered.
if set a default value in `useState('select')`;
then it works fine, but then the required option doesn't work.

Comment: could prevent the error with `selectedCategory?.value` if that's what you are looking for

Comment: @Smern - how to address it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `value` property on your `selectedCategory` object because it's default is null.

Try either optionally chaining or falsy checking like this:

```js
const [selectedCategory, setSelectedCategory] = useState(null);

<div className="col-12 col-lg-12 mb-3">
    <Select
        placeholder="Select Category..."
        id="selectCategory"
        required
        defaultValue={selectedCategory}
        //onKeyUp={setCategory}
        onChange={setSelectedCategory}
        options={serviceNames}
    />
</div>

<div className="col-12 col-lg-12">
    {selectedCategory?.value === 'other' && (
        <input
            className="form-control mb-3"
            id="serviceCategory"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Entery Category of your Serivce/business"
            name="serviceCategory"
            onChange={e => setNewCategory(e.target.value)}
        />
    )}
</div>
```

or

```js
const [selectedCategory, setSelectedCategory] = useState(null);

<div className="col-12 col-lg-12 mb-3">
    <Select
        placeholder="Select Category..."
        id="selectCategory"
        required
        defaultValue={selectedCategory}
        //onKeyUp={setCategory}
        onChange={setSelectedCategory}
        options={serviceNames}
    />
</div>

<div className="col-12 col-lg-12">
    {selectedCategory && selectedCategory.value === 'other' && (
        <input
            className="form-control mb-3"
            id="serviceCategory"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Entery Category of your Serivce/business"
            name="serviceCategory"
            onChange={e => setNewCategory(e.target.value)}
        />
    )}
</div>
```

Alternatively, you could initialize your state with an empty object like this:

`const [selectedCategory, setSelectedCategory] = useState({});`

...but that may have unintended side effects.

Comment: Hi @Ali Klein - but the required error is still not shown. the page is rendered now, but when I submit without selecting an option - the page doesn't show the validation required, but it shows error in console. though I have added the required attribute.

Comment: @Dinesh, That seems like a separate issue. I'd have to see your entire code to debug.